# Visual Studio 2019 script tags (in cshtml) between (function,global variable) go to definition (F12) doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

VS 2019 script tags (in cshtml) "Go to definition" doesn't work, but in VS 2015 it works.

```js
//javascript function in cshtml
<script>
function getSelectedItem() 
{
 var x = 100;
}

function onDetail() 
{
    var selectedItem = getSelectedItem(); //F12 go to definition doesn't work

    windowResult.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    windowResult.Status = true;
}
</script>
```

```js
//javascript global variable in cshtml

<script>

var _OperationType = 0;
var _FormType= 0;


function SetDefaultsParam()
{
    var param = {};
    param.Type= _OperationType;  //F12 go to definition doesn't work

    param.Formtype= _FormType;
    param.MasterId = _MasterId;
}
</script>
```

Function or global variable in cshtml (<kbd>F12</kbd>) "Go to definition" gives "Cannot navigate to the symbol........."

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the product, report it to the product team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio development team like to stress using the "Search Visual Studio (Ctrl-Q)" to find options.

[image: search example]

Bring up your keyboard mapping and make sure the Edit.GoToDefinition is mapped to F12 for example.

In testing, if the function is empty, it won't jump to it. But when I put in a line of code inside the function, F12 worked like a charm.  I am running VS2019 16.1.0 Preview 2.0.

[image: keyboard mapping]